# While Loop in [R]: syntax and keywords

Tags: r, while-loop

I want to implement a forward step-wise regression in R. BFP is a BodyFatPercentage data set, and I am trying to create a regression model to predict BODYFAT through step-wise regression. Keep getting an error

---

(Error: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level

> ```
>   }}
> ```
>
> ### Error: unexpected '}' in "      }"

with the following code:

```
  dataset <- BFP
  alpha   <- 0.01
  namestarget  <- 'BODYFAT'
  inde    <- c('AGE','WEIGHT','HEIGHT','NECK','CHEST','ABDOMEN',
           'HIP','THIGH','KNEE','ANKLE','BICEPS','FOREARM','WRIST')

  x <- 1
  counter <- 0
  indiLeft <- as.data.frame(subset(dataset)[inde])
  fmla_sub <- NULL
  fmla_sup <- NULL
  while (TRUE){
    print c('starting',counter,newx, indiLeft)
    correlations <- cor(dataset[target],indiLeft)
    newx <- colnames(correlations)[(which(correlations == max(correlations)))]

    fmla_sub <- as.formula(paste(target,"~", paste(x, collapse= "+")))
    fmla_sup <- as.formula(paste(target,"~", paste(c(x,newx), collapse= "+")))
    p <- anova(lm(fmla_sub,data=dataset),lm(fmla_sup,data=dataset), test="F")['Pr(>F)']

    if (p$'Pr(>F)'[2] < alpha){
      x<- c(x,newx)
      indiLeft <- indiLeft[-which(names(indiLeft) == newx)]
      counter <- counter +1
      next 
      }else{
        print ('while broken')
        print (fmla_sub)
        break
      }
  }
```

Can anyone figure out why this while loop only attempts the loop once?

Comment: You didn't even want to tell us the error? Quick glance though I notice that you put the start of the else block on the line after closing the if block.  This is a no-no in R.  Move that up to give `} else {`

Comment: Also, you know, you can't actually write `print x` in R without parentheses...

Comment: @Dason - Thanks for the }else{ tip. I seem to be getting the same error still. I appreciate you taking the time to help!

Comment: The mentioned error is only the last of a bundle of errors. Please reduce your example: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to set `p` to be a vector and I'm guessing that the first element of that vector is not what you think it is.

```
fit <- lm(sr ~ ., data = LifeCycleSavings)
anova(fit)
fit0 <- lm(sr ~ 1, data = LifeCycleSavings)
fit1 <- update(fit0, . ~ . + pop15)
p <- anova(fit0, fit1, test = "F")

> str(p)
Classes ‘anova’ and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Res.Df   : num  49 48
 $ RSS      : num  984 780
 $ Df       : num  NA 1
 $ Sum of Sq: num  NA 204
 $ F        : num  NA 12.6
 $ Pr(>F)   : num  NA 0.000887
```

If your `if()` command encountered that value it would evaluate only the NA value, fail and pass on to the `else` clause and exit.

Comment: thanks! This is a very helpful answer. However, I am still unable to run the while loop successfully. I have implemented the change you suggested here in the original post -- is this what you meant?